# Вывести кто онлайн через базу данных ? - MySQL

Tags: mysql

Ребята подскажите как вывести в админку кто сейчас онлайн на сайте авторизованные пользователи + нужно вывести на страницы объявления где указано имя пользователя онлайн он или офлаин.
Может кто поделится скриптом с инструкцией?

Также нужна функция которая создаст нужный столбец в базе данных так как там я вообще не чего не понимаю.
Или может это можно привязать к id_akk ?

[image: фото базы]

Comment: Показанная структура не позволяет узнать, когда авторизованный пользователь выполнил последнее действие - следовательно, невозможно предположить, онлайн он или нет, по причине отсутствия исходных данных.

Comment: а что еще нужно скажите я выложу ?

Comment: Нужна структура лога действий.

Comment: добавила новое фото

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо в таблице пользователей создать столбец `last_activity`(последняя активность) с типом данных хранящим дату, например `timestamp`, и при любом действии пользователя менять в ней значение на `NOW()`.

После чего определять кто онлайн можно используя эту колонку.

Например, можно считать онлайн людей, у которых `last_activity-time()<5`.

Comment: можете помочь это реализовать ?

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего это делать в каком нибудь in-memory key-value хранилище(Memcached, Redis) с возможностью устаревания данных.

При каждом авторизованном действии пользователя или при авторизации(не путать с аутентификацией) обновляете значение в кеше, например.
При деаутентификации удаляете значение.

Когда нужно, получаете список живых значений.

Пример на Redis:

```
SET users_online_42 42 60 ; set user#42 online for next 60 sec
DEL users_online_42       ; set user#42 offline
KEYS users_online_*       ; список ключей для пользователей онлайн, можно получить конкретный id как подстроку или через GET key
```